# Where / How to specify Topic ARN in SNS http end point using spring aws-cloud

Tags: java, spring, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

I am writing a SNS http end point using spring aws-cloud messaging support as specified in this [link](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_http_notification_endpoint) for my spring boot web application. How should I specify the topic ARN using aws-cloud ? What is actually meant by the below important note in this [link](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_http_notification_endpoint):

> Currently it is not possible to define the mapping URL on the method level therefore the RequestMapping must be done at type level and must contain the full path of the endpoint.